# txt в mysql 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php

Совершаю txt выгрузку в mysql средствами php.
Количество строк в документе 100.000+.
Выбираем файл, сохраняю файл на сервере, открываю файл для чтения, построчно считываю и записываю данные в массив, передаю массив в функцию которая загружает данные в бд (CMS WP).
Примерно на 3 797 получаю (504 Gateway Time-out).

```
function post_integration($arr, $array) {

    global $wpdb;

    $cat = $array['category'];
    $manufacturer = $array['manufacturer'];
    $return_status = $array['return_status'];
    $markup = $array['markup'];


    for ( $i = 1, $j=0; $i < count($arr); $i++, $j++ )
    {

        set_time_limit(0);
        $vendor_code = ( iconv ("CP1251", "UTF-8", $arr[$i][0]) );
        $vendor_code = substr($vendor_code, 1);
        $product_name = ( iconv ("CP1251", "UTF-8", $arr[$i][1]) );
        $price = ( iconv ("CP1251", "UTF-8", $arr[$i][2]) );
        $rabat_group = ( iconv ("CP1251", "UTF-8", $arr[$i][3]) );
        $product_desc = ( iconv ("CP1251", "UTF-8", $arr[$i][4]) );
        $mortgage_value = ( iconv ("CP1251", "UTF-8", $arr[$i][5]) );
        $netto_weight = ( iconv ("CP1251", "UTF-8", $arr[$i][6]) );
        $netto_weight = substr($netto_weight, 0, -1);

        $price = str_replace(",",".",$price);

        $this_price =  ( ($markup / 100) * $price) + $price;
        $end_price = round($this_price, 2);


        $query="SELECT vendor_code.meta_value AS \"vendor_code\", p.ID AS \"ID\" FROM wp_posts p
        JOIN wp_postmeta vendor_code ON p.ID = vendor_code.post_id AND vendor_code.meta_key = 'vendor_code'
        WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND vendor_code.meta_value = $vendor_code";

        $rabrt_id_query = "SELECT id FROM `wp_rabat_list` WHERE name_rabat = '$manufacturer'";

        $result_data = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        $rabat_data = $wpdb->get_results($rabrt_id_query);

        $rabat_id = $rabat_data[0]->id;
        $result_id = $result_data[0]->ID;
        $result_vendor = $result_data[0]->vendor_code;

        if(isset($result_vendor)) {

            $my_post = array();
            $my_post['ID'] = intval($result_id);
            $my_post['post_title'] = wp_strip_all_tags($product_name);
            $my_post['post_content'] = $product_desc;
            $my_post['post_category'] = array($cat);

            wp_update_post($my_post);

            update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'vendor_code', $vendor_code);
            update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'price', $end_price);
            update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'manufacturer', $manufacturer);
            update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'mortgage_value', $mortgage_value);
            update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'netto_weight', $netto_weight);
            // update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'availability', $article);
            update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'return_goods', $return_status);
            update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'discount_group_id', $rabat_id);
            update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'mark_up', $markup);

        }
        else
        {
            $post_data = array(
              'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $product_name ),
              'post_content'  => $product_desc,
              'post_status'   => 'publish',
              'post_author'   => 1,
              'post_category' => array($cat)
            );
            //Вставляем запись в базу данных
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

            add_post_meta($post_id, 'vendor_code', $vendor_code);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'price', $end_price);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'manufacturer', $manufacturer);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'mortgage_value', $mortgage_value);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'netto_weight', $netto_weight);
            // add_post_meta($post_id, 'availability', $article);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'return_goods', $return_status);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'discount_group_id', $rabat_id);
            update_post_meta($my_post['ID'], 'mark_up', $markup);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Если этот сервер ваш, то нужно поправить настройки, чтобы он не отбрасывал соединение, если есть провайдер, то связать с тех поддержкой и объяснить им вашу ситуацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте запускать это долгий процесс в фоне:
test.php - ваш скрипт, который загружает txt в БД

```
<?php
    exec("/path/to/file/test.php &");
?>
```

или вообще из консоли, если есть такая возможность:

```
php /path/to/file/test.php
```

так же можно попробовать увеличить время работы скрипта, написав в начале

```
set_time_limit(сколько секунд)
```

Comment: Вариант с консолью не получится, необходимо чтоб решение работало с административного кабинета. Т.е. это плагин который грузит огромные txt файлы с товарами в бд.

Comment: Хост написал что не дает возможности для работы с exec

Comment: можно попробовать увеличить время выполнения set_time_limit(3600), но имхо нормальный хостинг должен давать возможность работы с exec :(

Comment: Да я уже смерился)
Заказчик в прод возьмет VPS.
Сейчас буду разбивать на файлы и грузить все отдельно, решение не самое лучшее, но нужно чтоб работало)
На прод сделаю exec!

Comment: Если БД можно управлять через phpmyadmin. То можно сконвертировать txt в sql и попробовать импортировать.

Comment: Это импорт в всеми любимый WordPress,  так просто в sql сконвертировать не получиться